# Is there and visualization software to create a sdf file? Eg-: can we create a sdf file from a CAD model etc

Tags: gazebo, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there and visualization software to create a sdf file? Eg-: can we create a sdf file from a CAD model etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3258/is-there-and-visualization-software-to-create-a-sdf-file?-eg-:-can-we-create-a-sdf-file-from-a-cad-model-etc./) by [rohanbhargava11](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/393/rohanbhargava11/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use the [SolidWorks URDF exporter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sw_urdf_exporter) to export from SolidWorks to URDF and then you can convert URDF to SDF (or simply stick with URDF and have Gazebo convert it at runtime).

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0